# How to tell if an android activity is currently displayed as a dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity in a library project that may or may not be displayed as a dialog. If it is, I want to set its height and width. Is there a way to determine in onCreate that the current theme is a dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually decided to have two activities, one called WizardActivity and the other called WizardDialog. I've got samples in the library of how to set these up in the manifest and it's left up to the developer using my library to ensure the themes are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection -- just call this method from your onCreate().

```
public boolean isDialog() {
    boolean isDialog;
    try {
        Method method = ContextThemeWrapper.class.getMethod("getThemeResId");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        int themeResId = (Integer) method.invoke(this);
        // TODO: replace Theme_Dialog with the Theme you're using
        isDialog = themeResId == android.R.style.Theme_Dialog; 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Error getting theme resource ID
        isDialog = false;
    }       
    return isDialog;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the activity is in a library project so I won't have any control over what the theme is. I'm afraid I may just need two static methods to start the activity: one to start it as an activity and one to start it as a dialog. Then I'll just have to trust the developer who is using my library to match the proper theme with how he starts the activity.